What is the source of outliers in this C++ benchmark?
I'm running this C++ code measuring a very short time interval it takes to add two numbers on Ubuntu 22.04. I don't care about the measurement itself, since this is not an appropriate method to measure a single instruction time, but care about repeatability. Here is the code:
int main() {
  constexpr int n = 10'000'000;

  vector<float> timings;
  int64_t       result = 0;

  timings.reserve(n+1);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    auto t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    result += i;
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    timings.push_back(duration<float, micro>{t1-t0}.count());  
  }

  sort(timings.begin(), timings.end());
  println("\nmin: {:.3f}us  med: {:.3f}us  99%: {:.3f}us  max: {:.3f}us  {}\n", 
    timings[0], timings[timings.size()/2], timings[99*timings.size()/100], timings.back(), result);

  for (int i = timings.size()-9; i < timings.size(); i++)
    println("{:.3f} ", timings[i]);
}

It produces:
min: 0.020us  med: 0.020us  99%: 0.030us  max: 181.702us  49999995000000

104.366 
107.432 
138.891 
140.454 
142.368 
143.409 
145.293 
150.453 
181.702 

There are numerous outliers 5K times longer than the median. What is the source of them? Is it the overhead of calling high_resolution_clock::now()? OS context switch between calls to high_resolution_clock::now()?

To clarify. I'm not using a microbenchmarking suite, because as stated above, I don't care about how long result += i takes. It is a placeholder for something else, which is impossible to include in this post. I only care about outliers. This code snippet shows that the measurement method itself produces outliers, therefore it has to be improved. My use case is sensitive to outliers and I want to get an idea about the worst case scenario.
I'm trying to run the test at real-time priority, but have problems to set it up. Running it as a user process at maximum priority on a dedicated core does not remove outliers.

In order to isolate from OS activity, I installed Ubuntu realtime kernel with pro enable realtime-kernel and added GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nohz=on nohz_full=15 rcu_nocbs=15 isolcpus=15 irqaffinity=0-14" to grub. I also call sched_setaffinity() for core #15. I'm running 1G iterations and see much smaller outliers:
1,000,000,000 iterations  PID 461962  NICE -20  core #15
min: 0.012us  med: 0.020us  99%: 0.023us  max: 13.731us  499999999500000000

7.636 
9.137 
9.760 
12.583 
13.145 
13.240 
13.585 
13.682 
13.731 


Are you running this program at normal priority?  If so, you might try running at highest/real-time priority and see if that makes the timing more consistent.  If it does, then it's a good bet that your program was occasionally getting pre-empted by some other task.

most likely noise from the OS.  Ideally you run the loop for some tens or hundreds of thousands of times and then you divide the total time by the number of iterations to get the per op timing.

That said micro benchmarking is hard to do right.  So many times the compiler will optimize operations away since they "do nothing".  Tools like google benchmark can really help with this issue.  quick-bench is an online version that you can test with

Use steady_clock ... high_resolution_clock may not be stable ...

use an actual benchmarking framework

Your program run can be interrupted. You might want to discard 5-10% of the highest values. The median value is fair enough.

@NathanOliver I added an explanation to my post. I'm not trying to measure execution time of result += i.

But that other task runs as short as result += i? If it's longer, are the outliers gone?

@ThomasWeller It's longer, but has a similar median to the longest time difference, therefore the measurement method may be the cause.

@ChrisMM Good point. high_resolution_clock::is_steady is false on my system.

@ChrisMM OTOH, steady_clock only guarantees monotonicity. I don't think high_resolution_clock has any more wobble than steady_clock. high_resolution_clock rollover would show as a negative time period, which I didn't see.

Use a profiler, it will tell you about missed branche predictions, cache misses, etc. etc.. Using a clock from code is just not good enough. Also it might just be your PC suddenly starts doing different things like running a virus scanner.

@PepijnKramer "missed branche predictions, cache misses" are too short to be responsible for 0.1ms outliers.

It is the OS doing things in the background. Realistically the only binary operation that you can just about measure the way you are going about it is divide. All of the others are one cycle to execute provided that both arguments are available. Also without a side effect of printing out result you are very lucky the compiler didn't optimise the loop to oblivion. Timing how long it takes to do 10^9 operations and making sure that you have side effects to defeat the optimiser is the way to do it. Don't try to roll your own benchmarking code there are decent frameworks out there to use.

@PaulJurczak That's the result of too small, too naive tests, good testing/benchmarking/profiling is not trivial (and thus the tests OP posted are overall pretty naive and not good enoug to draw conclussions)


I'm trying to run the test at real-time priority, but have problems to set it up.

Fix those problems. Using any policy other than SCHED_RR or SCHED_FIFO gives an obvious source of outliers.

Running it as a user process at maximum priority on a dedicated core does not remove outliers.

High priority doesn't prevent pre-emption, it just means the scheduler is more likely to hand control back to your process than a different one, afterwards.
Run your program under /bin/time to confirm it's being affected by context switches. Watch the core in top/htop/whatever to see what else is getting scheduled there (make sure the display includes kernel threads).
Assuming it is being pre-empted, preventing it requires something like:

binding it to a core
isolating that core from the scheduler (isolcpus kernel parameter)
steering interrupts away from that core (irqaffinity kernel parameter)
disabling clock ticks on that core (nohz_full kernel parameter)

There may be other kernel options needed, and you may need to tinker with these to get the right result, and obviously you'll have to reboot in order to change them. For perfectly solid results, you may need to recompile the kernel with different options.
Don't forget to make sure your cpufreq governor is performance on at least the selected core.

All of this is why it's much easier (and not much less accurate) to simply take a lot of samples and discard outliers.

By dedicated core, I meant 1 and 2 of your list. I used cset shield.

With what options, exactly? If you have more details of how you ran the benchmark, please edit them into the question.

I edited the post. Thank you for your advice.

You don't show the cset shield options or output though? Or did you just take the boot parameters and stop using cset?

Just the boot parameters, cset is redundant, right?
